# How to read values from properties file with html

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my html snippet

```html
First name:
<input type = "text" >
Last name:
<input type = "text">
```

Instead of hard coding the field values (First name,Last name) in the html I want to read them from a property file is this possible just with html.please suggest me a way to do it.

Comment: Please elaborate what kind of property file you want to read from. You can read values from a file using PHP.

Comment: I am working on a java project so I want to read the values from a simple text file separated with ":" like this namefield: First Name etc. so I have to read the property file and get the First Name using the key namefield in place of above First Name.

Comment: Your questions is not clear. You cannot read a file with html, you need a server side language... Also if you read only the labels (First name, Last name) what name will you give to the inputs? I assume the inputs will be in a form. After submit the form will be processed by a server side language which will need names for the inputs. There are missing so many things from your question...

Comment: I got your point, you cannot directly access these values without any code. This type of requirement comes when you want some localization based on language. and hence you dont want to hard code the value in HTML file. So we need to write a node js program, which first reads the key to be replaced from the html file and finds the corresponding value from the properties file and then replace it in html file. After doing this process, you need to run this program as part of the build process every time. The later step you can add it as a grunt task.

Comment: What you're looking to do in my opinion to is to populate the values from another file. Are you using JavaScript, php, c#, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can read a file using ajax(XMLHttpReqeust).

with no plugins:

```
First name:
<input id="first_name" type="text">
Last name:
<input id="last_name" type="text">
<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    var data = xmlhttp.responseText; // use JSON.parse if properties file is formatted as json
    document.getElementById('first_name').value = data; // use like this
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET", "properties.txt", true);
xmlhttp.send();
</script>
```

Comment: hi but I don't want to write First name and Last name values in the html i want to get those from property file

Comment: change "properties.txt" to property file and insert `alert(data);` after `xmlhttp.responseText;`

Answer (score -1):

Just put a file in the same folder as the html and load it with JQuery ajax:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="name" />
<input type="text" id="last_name" />
<script>
$(function(){
$.ajax({
    url:'config.json',
    type:'GET',
    success:function(data){
        var tmpData = JSON.parse(data);
        $("#name").val(tmpData.name);
        $("#last_name").val(tmpData.last_name);
    }
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

config.json

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe"
}
```